# Adding small order surcharge fee and making it taxed?

Tags: php, woocommerce, tax, fee

I am using this piece of code found elsewhere on stackoverflow, it applies a surcharge to bring the cart total up to £25, it works correctly except that tax (VAT) is only being calculated based on the original sub total rather than the total including the surcharge - very new to PHP, not sure what to change or add, any help greatly received :)

```
//ADD SMALL ORDER SURCHARGE IN CART
function woo_add_cart_fee( $cart ) {
if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
return;

    // Get subtotal
    $subt = $cart->get_subtotal();

    // Below
    if ($subt < 25 ) {
        $surcharge = 25 - $subt;
 
        $cart->add_fee( __('Min. £25 Small order charge', 'woocommerce' ), $surcharge );
    }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee' );
```

Comment: so what's the question then?

Comment: Ah, how to get the additional cart fee / surcharge to be taxable in the cart

Comment: Maybe another $subt = $cart->get_subtotal(); at the end of the if?

Comment: There is a tax argument for `add_fee` function, which you have not added in your code. [Woocommerce WC_Cart documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Cart.html). Try replacing `$cart->add_fee( __('Min. £25 Small order charge', 'woocommerce' ), $surcharge );` with `$cart->add_fee( __('Min. £25 Small order charge', 'woocommerce' ), $surcharge, true, ' ' );`

Comment: Richard - that works perfectly, thanks so much for taking the time :)